# How to send access token using a wss .net client

Tags: nest-api

I want to connect to the nest endpoint using a .net wss client.
I am unsure how to pass the NEST access_token during handshake to the endpoint to complete
the authorization handshake.

- Without it I get a 401.
- If I put is as query parameter  "/devices.json?auth=c.Uysdi..." I get
  a 307 (redirection) to a firebase endpoint but with https ??? (no
  longer wss).
- If i add the access token to headers I get 401.

In the api samples I can only find javascript examples using firebase client lib which
does not help much.
Can someone explain what should I do to complete the wss handshake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. 
There was a 'bug' in the web socket library I was using. The header value "Upgrade: websocket"
which is passed during websocket handshake was passed like this "Upgrade: web**S**ocket".
Some websocket test servers are case insensitive but not the one from Google Nest.
Once I changed this to "websocket" I got a proper websocket handshake response and no redirection either.
Access token is added as a query parameter when connecting with websockets to the nest endpoint.

Once the connection is established I am again in the dark on how to establish subscribtion to certain
events or query data but this will be the topic for another question.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the https with wss. that worked for me.
Maybe a bit of code will help people solve you issue